# Eclipse IDE 2019‑06 not showing proposals after breaking nested loop

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure where to post this. I may have found a bug in Eclipse IDE 2019‑06 or I'm missing something in the preferences options somewhere.

After breaking out of a for loop like so

```
a:for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    break a;
}

System.<No Default Proposals>
```

I get no proposals in the content assist menu for anything after. Is there any way to solve this? The version is the current available on the Eclipse download site.

Comment: This [`bugreport`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548508) is somewhat similiar. It also seems to affect other eclipse versions (like 2019-03). -- But the real question is why would you write code like this?

Comment: It's for example. Nothing intended other than to show how it occurs. Bumped into it while scanning a list containing an object with a list inside that needed to break completely at first match. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **known issue** that has already been **fixed**.

The fix will be included **in the upcoming Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)** which will be released on September 18th.

For details see [Eclipse bug 547256](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547256) and [Eclipse bug 548476](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548476).